# Front Page extensions installation on IIS 7.0

Tags: iis-7, frontpage

My story short:  I run Windows Server 2008 (not the R2 version, the x32) with IIS 7.
I downloaded the Front Page extensions from the only place on the web: http://www.rtr.com/fpse/Win2008R2/

It will not install, because this version is for Windows 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5.

I looked all over the Internet for FPSE for IIS 7.0 for half of day, and nothing.
I am really desperate, I am working with FPSE for more than 10 years now..

Does anybody know where to find the right extensions?? Or any tricks?

I thank you in advance for your help!

Regards,
Simona

Comment: The site links to an iis7 version? http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1630

Answer (score 0):

Go here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1173013.aspx.

Has links to two different dls - iis7 and iis7.5